# Unable to use moment.js when aggregating in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, date, momentjs

I am using aggregation pipeline like so:

```
Model.aggregate([
  $project:{
    expiry: moment("$date_expired").format('h')}]
,function(err,res){...});
```

The `"$date_expired"` is a date in the Schema.

But, when I try to get the results from the above aggregation, I get an error
`FieldPath \'Invalid date\' doesn\'t start with $`

What could be the error and how do I solve it?

Comment: Can you not use the `$hour` aggregation in Mongo? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/hour/

Comment: Yeah, but I need to get the difference, so then, I would have to use `$substract` too. Just wanted an easier solution as I am using moment already in my app.

Answer (score 1):

you can use ***$function*** in aggregate but you shoud upgrade mongodb to v4.4

```
     Model.aggregate([
     { $addFields:{
        expiry: {
          $function:{
            body:function(date_expire){return moment(date_expired).format('h')},
           args:['$date_expire'],
           lang:"js"
        }}
     }])
```

Comment: if you just need 'h' you could use other functions like $dateToString and use format and timezon options to get data on any format that you want

Comment: oh thank you . this helped me a lot . this should be marked as answer

Answer (score -2):

This is never going to work. `moment` is a function in your node.js code, but the aggregation runs in MongoDB.

If you want it to run `moment('$fieldInYourSchema')` as it iterates, it's not going to work because moment will actually run before calling the aggregation (e.g when you are constructing the array to submit to the db).

Answer (score -3):

you should try:

```
Model.aggregate([
  $project:{
    expiry: moment($date_expired).format('h')}]
,function(err,res){...});
```

beacuse

```
$date_expired
```

is a variable so you should not use "" for it.

Comment: No. It's not a variable. It's a property in the results of MongoDB. And, it's written like that with a `$` before the name of the property.

Comment: yeah. I did. And it obviously threw Unknown Variable error.

Comment: As you are using angular on a definition of function. You can not pass it on a argument. try passing the updated content while you calling a model.